# IIS rewrite rule - How to omit 'index' text from website name when website opened in browser

Tags: php, iis

I am using below IIS rewrite rule for index.php page of website.

```
<rule name="INDEX">
<match url="^(.*)index$" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">  
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />  
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(user/inc|user/img)" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
</conditions> 
</rule>
```

When I access www.sitename.com, it adds index at the end of website like www.sitename.com/index.

I want to do so if I write www.websitename.com or www.websitename.com/index, it should just show www.sitename.com. Please let me know how can I do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out the solution for my issue.

Add following code in web.config file before writing any rules. Also change path of index.php page according to path in website.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>

        <defaultDocument enabled="true">
            <files>
                <remove value="user/index.php" />
                <add value="user/index.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>

        <rewrite>  
            <rules>
                <rule name="INDEX">
                    <match url="^(.*)index$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="user/index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">  
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />  
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(user/inc|user/img)" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions> 
                </rule>
            </rules>  
        </rewrite>

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```